# App crashes when POST using Okhttp in AlertDialog Kotlin

Tags: android, json, kotlin, android-alertdialog, okhttp

I have created a form in AlertDialog. Now I'm trying to post it using Okhttp with all the fields filled, but my app crashes with following message.

Error:

```
2019-10-12 23:34:27.579 26232-26232/com.kabelash.todolistbboxx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.kabelash.todolistbboxx, PID: 26232
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: tskName must not be null
        at com.kabelash.todolistbboxx.MainActivity$addNewTask$1.onClick(MainActivity.kt:47)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:167)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Note: txtName is not null at all when submitting the form.

Code for AlertDialog in Kotlin:

```
val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        val inflater = layoutInflater
        builder.setTitle(R.string.add_new_task)
        val dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_new_task, null)
        builder.setView(dialogLayout)
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.save) { dialogInterface, i ->

            val name = tskName.text.toString().trim()
            val status = tskStatus.text.toString().trim()
            val description = tskDesc.text.toString().trim()
            val expiry_date = tskDate.text.toString().trim()

            val client = OkHttpClient()

            val formBody = FormBody.Builder()
                .add("name", name)
                .add("status", status)
                .add("description", description)
                .add("expiry_date", expiry_date)
                .build()
            val request = Request.Builder()
                .url("https://someurl.com")
                .post(formBody)
                .build()

            try {
                val response = client.newCall(request).execute()

                val body = response.body?.string()
                println(body)
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }


        }
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null)
        builder.show()
```

Someone Please help me to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not show at all where `tskName` is coming from. It looks like you're using some kind of view injection where `tskName` is the name of a widget on the screen. If this view injection did not work properly, it might have not properly found the requested view by it's ID or a view with that particular ID is present in some layout file of yours, but not inflated on screen (a common issue when using the Kotlin Android Extensions that allow you to simply "import" widgets by their `android:id` name).